# Make linq aware of uniqe ID

Tags: c#, linq

I have a small question. How do i make linq aware that some columns are uniqe

fx. I have a table, with columns "ID" and "Name"

ID is auto incrementing Primary key. Name is just varchar(255)

The result of a linq like this:

```
from item in db.ItemSet
where item.ID == 1
select item
```

Im left with a IQueryable. But there can be only 1 item, with "ID"==1
How do i tell linq this.

At the moment i do this

```
(from item in db.ItemSet
 where item.ID == 1
 select item).First()
```

But I would consider this a "hack"...

Comment: Since `ID` is the primary key, it *already knows*; for example, LINQ-to-SQL will (for the `.First()` usage you already show) try to do an lookup via the identity-cache, to save on a round-trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.Single()` instead of `.First()`.

However, both of those assume that the record exists and will throw an exception if no record is found. If there's a potential for looking up a record that does not exist, you may want to consider `.FirstOrDefault()` / `.SingleOrDefault()`.

Further reading:

- [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72475/LINQ-Single-vs-First)
- [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/928a4ed4-8fc1-4677-b22a-a9f8af83b4c3)

Comment: What a strange comparison on the [codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72475/LINQ-Single-vs-First) you've provided. First taxi or my single car, if there are more, exception. Huh?

Answer (score 3):

If you're only expecting one, use single

```
(from item in db.ItemSet
 where item.ID == 1
 select item).Single()
```

In fact you could clean up even more and do this;

```
db.ItemSet.Single(item.ID == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SingleOrDefault` or `Single`

```
var result = db.ItemSet.Single(r=>r.ID == 1);
```

[Single from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx)

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if
>   there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Since primary key can't be duplicate, you can use `Single` because if more than one value is there in the resultset, it will throw exception.

You may use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), if you only want either `one` or `none` result.

EDIT: as far as making LINQ aware of primary key in :

```
from item in db.ItemSet
where item.ID == 1
select item
```

You can't make LINQ to return a single item of type `ItemSet`. Although ID is the primary key, but LINQ is querying against a collection and will return a collection not a single item of type `ItemSet`

Answer (score 0):

In your class declaration you could use the KeyAttribute constructor. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx